# I have HAXM installed ,but android studio can't find my virtual device

Tags: android-studio, flutter

i am trying to open a virtual device (this is my first time trying android studio) and Haxm is already installed but it everytime i click on new devices it says nothing here.**please help**

Comment: You want to run on emulator or physical device?

Comment: Have you enabled VT-X of your system?